# iMacros - Change date Format

Tags: date, format, date-format, imacros

I have an iMacros script working with data extracted from csv file.
I am trying to change a format date different as is extracted from  my csv file.
I need
08-24-2022  to be replaced with  Aug 24, 2022
basically d-mmm-yy   with  mmm d, yyyy

I tried something like this,, don't know how to make it work, Thank you for support!

```
SET date "08-24-2022"
SET dateFormatted EVAL("\"{{date}}\".replace(/(\\d{4})-(\\d\\d)-(\\d\\d)/, \"$2 $3, $1\");")
PROMPT {{dateFormatted}}
```

I am using:
Browser: Google Chrome Version 105.0.5195.102 (Official Build) (64-bit)

iMacros Personal Edition License - Addon for Chrome -Version 10.1.1

Windows 10 (64-bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One "easy" Implementation: Declare the Months yourself in a Var/Array and use the Month Number as Index (to re-`split()` the Array into the 12 Months) to convert it to the `mmm` Format, stg like:

```scala
VERSION BUILD=8820413 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1

SET date "08-24-2022"
'SET dateFormatted EVAL("\"{{date}}\".replace(/(\\d{4})-(\\d\\d)-(\\d\\d)/, \"$2 $3, $1\");")

SET Months _Jan_Feb_Mar_Apr_May_Jun_Jul_Aug_Sep_Oct_Nov_Dec_

SET dateFormatted EVAL("var d='{{date}}', m='{{Months}}', x,y,z; x=d.split('-'); y=m.split('_')[x[0]*1]; z=y+' '+x[1]+', '+x[2]; z;")
PROMPT _{{dateFormatted}}_
```

For Date="08-24-2022", this will output `Aug 24, 2022`.
For Date="08-04-2022", this will output `Aug 04, 2022`.
(=> Use `x[1]*1` instead of `x[1]` in `z` if you would prefer `Aug 4, 2022` for 1-Digit Dates from `01`-`09` to remove the Leading 0...)

(Written and tested in `iMacros for FF v8.8.2, PM v26.3.3, Win10_PRO_21H2`.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! its working for me also in both version 01 an 1 for day of the month.  best wishes

Comment: Ahhh!! I see now, actually my csv remain mostlly like: 28-Aug-22, 
1-Sep-22 so SET date "1-Sep-22"  or  SET date "28-Aug-22"  . How can be the code for this date format? thank you again for your help

Comment: I found a way. csv can be saved in 8/28/2022 date format, so was easy for me to replace "-" with "/". Thank you again for your time making this

Comment: Yep-yep indeed the `x=d.split('-')` is meant for a Date in "08-24-2022" Format (=> with `-` Separator), and the Dashes are used in the `split()` to separate the 3 Parts in the Date, would you have a Date in "08/24/2022" Format, =>simply adapt the `split()` to use the `/` Separator instead of `-` like you correctly understood...

Comment: Mini-Detail, I see that you've already opened 2 new Threads, I haven't had a look yet, but hum, any chance you could read the iMacros Tag [wiki](/imacros/info)...?, I "normally" don't answer when FCI is not included in a Post/Qt... (so I was "nice" for this one), + correct Spelling is "iMacros"... :idea: